# Joomla 3 не понятна работа ЧПУ

Tags: joomla, чпу

Имеется сайт, включено чпу, работает нормально. Стал замечать, что выдаются ссылки типа site.ru/index.php?id=114&Itemid=173&option=com_content&view=article или можно получить материал, указав просто site.ru/123 где 123 это id материала. Кто сталкивался и как это исправить?

**UPD:**

Часть проблемы исправил, найдя такое решение:

nginx

```
set $arg_set "${arg_option}___${arg_view}___${arg_id}";
    if ($arg_set ~* "^(((\w|-)+?)___){2}((\w|-)+?)$") {
        return 404;
    }
```

Осталось решить проблему с указанием site.ru/114 где 114 - это id статьи.

Comment: Телепатов тут нет, надо смотреть каким образом был настроен SEF. И настроен ли вообще т.к. при верной настройке все урл проходят через трансформацию. Возможно ваши ссылки - это устаревшие линки, которые были до процесса SEF. Опишите более подробно где вы получаете ссылки "старого" типа.  Если перенаправление URL-адресов не работает, возможно, ваш хостинг не может активировать модуль mod_rewrite на сервере Apache. Свяжитесь с хостером, чтобы получить возможность использовать данные функции.

Comment: Укажите канонический url на своих страницах https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=ru

Comment: @alexoander у меня связка на vps nginx + php-fpm. До переезда на vps было тоже самое, не могу понять где я в свое время накосячил. SEF стандартный, Включить SEF (ЧПУ) - вкл, Перенаправление URL - вкл, Добавлять суффикс к URL - вкл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил установкой плагина JL No Dubles.